# I'm getting ORA-00936: missing expression. Why is that? Can someone help me out?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT ALL
INTO EMPLOYEE 
(EMPL_CODE_ID, EMPL_FIRST_NAME, EMPL_LAST_NAME, EMPL_ADDRESS, 
EMPL_WORKING_AREA, EMPL_TITLE, EMPL_PHONE_NUMBER, EMPL_DOB, 
EMPL_STATE, EMPL_COUNTRY)
VALUES
('A4','ROB','BOB','123 TREE TOP','FRONT DESK','RECEPTIONIST','301-000-0004','01/04/1994','MD','USA')

INTO EMPLOYEE 
(EMPL_CODE_ID, EMPL_FIRST_NAME, EMPL_LAST_NAME, EMPL_ADDRESS, 
EMPL_WORKING_AREA, EMPL_TITLE, EMPL_PHONE_NUMBER, EMPL_DOB, 
EMPL_STATE, EMPL_COUNTRY)
VALUES
('A5','JOSH','FROG','125 TREE BARK LANE','FRONT DESK','RECEPTIONIST','301-000-0005','08/09/1994','VA','USA')
INTO EMPLOYEE 
(EMPL_CODE_ID, EMPL_FIRST_NAME, EMPL_LAST_NAME, EMPL_ADDRESS, 
EMPL_WORKING_AREA, EMPL_TITLE, EMPL_PHONE_NUMBER, EMPL_DOB, 
EMPL_STATE, EMPL_COUNTRY)
VALUES
INTO EMPLOYEE 
(EMPL_CODE_ID, EMPL_FIRST_NAME, EMPL_LAST_NAME, EMPL_ADDRESS, 
EMPL_WORKING_AREA, EMPL_TITLE, EMPL_PHONE_NUMBER, EMPL_DOB, 
EMPL_STATE, EMPL_COUNTRY)
VALUES
INTO EMPLOYEE 
(EMPL_CODE_ID, EMPL_FIRST_NAME, EMPL_LAST_NAME, EMPL_ADDRESS, 
EMPL_WORKING_AREA, EMPL_TITLE, EMPL_PHONE_NUMBER, EMPL_DOB, 
EMPL_STATE, EMPL_COUNTRY)
VALUES 
('A6','FRED','KIM','123 SENECA WAY','FRONT DESK','RECEPTIONIST','301-000-0006','03/23/1997','VA','USA')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: On another topic, `SELECT * FROM DUAL` is rather unusual.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that you´re missing values at the third and forth "INTO EMPLOYEE" statement.

Comment: I also concur with this assessment.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of inserting records into a single table is the straightforward `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM`. Use UNION ALL to make a set of records:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE 
(EMPL_CODE_ID, EMPL_FIRST_NAME, EMPL_LAST_NAME, EMPL_ADDRESS, EMPL_WORKING_AREA, EMPL_TITLE, EMPL_PHONE_NUMBER, EMPL_DOB, EMPL_STATE, EMPL_COUNTRY)
select 'A4','ROB','BOB','123 TREE TOP','FRONT DESK','RECEPTIONIST','301-000-0004','01/04/1994','MD','USA'
from dual union all
select 'A5','JOSH','FROG','125 TREE BARK LANE','FRONT DESK','RECEPTIONIST','301-000-0005','08/09/1994','VA','USA'
from dual union all
select 'A6','FRED','KIM','123 SENECA WAY','FRONT DESK','RECEPTIONIST','301-000-0006','03/23/1997','VA','USA'
from dual 
/
```